# SVN in Xcode can't be used when Xcode is upgraded to 6.4

Tags: ios, svn, xcode6.4

Why can't I use SVN in Xcode to update and commit my code when I upgrade my Xcode to 6.4?

Comment: Have you installed the latest versions of the comandline tools tools ?

Comment: I've replaced the SVN* files in Xcode/Contents/Developer/usr with the system's, and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I've replaced the SVN related files in Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ with the system's, and the problem is solved.